# How to programmatically set maxLength in Android TextView?

Tags: android, textview, maxlength

I would like to programmatically set `maxLength` property of `TextView` as I don't want to hard code it in the layout. I can't see any `set` method related to `maxLength`.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 380, accepted):

Should be something like that. but never used it for textview, only edittext :

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
int maxLength = 10;
InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
tv.setFilters(fArray);
```

Comment: Building upon that, it might be much cleaner to go: tv.setFilters( new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10) } );

Comment: Couldn't just say "maxLength()".. no, no, no.. that would be too easy. they had to make abstract it.. yay!

Comment: But this will reset your previous filters, no ?

Comment: With Kotlin you can make it cleaner: editText.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(10))

Comment: `editText.filters = arrayOf(*editText.filters, InputFilter.LengthFilter(10))` keep old filters with kotlin

Answer (score 90):

Try this

```
int maxLengthofEditText = 4;    
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLengthofEditText)});
```

Comment: This works for me, but in Android 5.1 you can still continue to type letters, the are yust "invisible" in the inputfield. But they are shown in the text  proposal. And when you try to delete letters on the end.

Comment: This is not "another way" this is the short version of the first answer, same way.

Answer (score 24):

For those of you using Kotlin

```
fun EditText.limitLength(maxLength: Int) {
    filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength))
}
```

Then you can just use a simple editText.limitLength(10)

Comment: why not use setMaxLength as function name ? you could apply this to textview also... thanks +1 :)

Comment: I have other methods that follow this pattern: limitDecimalPlaces, limitNumberOnly, limitAscii to go along with limitLength.

Comment: filters = filters.plus(InputFilter.LengthFilter(max))  Don't overwrite existing ones

Answer (score 22):

Easy way **limit edit text character** :

```
EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittxt);
ed.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(15)});
```

Answer (score 15):

As [João Carlos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52005780/2914140) said, in Kotlin use:

```
editText.filters += InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/58372842/2914140 about some devices strange behaviour.

(Add `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` to your `EditText`.)

Comment: Its create bug if you want to change length latter like in my case I change MaxLength from 10 to 20, but as in code we add filter its remain set MaxLength 10 bcus now in array we have 10,20 two max lengths.

Comment: @Nikhil, agree with you, thanks! Yes, in this case we should first remove one filter (`LengthFilter(10)`) and then add another (`LengthFilter(20)`).

Answer (score 8):

For Kotlin and without resetting previous filters:

```
fun TextView.addFilter(filter: InputFilter) {
  filters = if (filters.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    arrayOf(filter)
  } else {
    filters.toMutableList()
      .apply {
        removeAll { it.javaClass == filter.javaClass }
        add(filter)
      }
      .toTypedArray()
  }
}

textView.addFilter(InputFilter.LengthFilter(10))
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a simple extension function for this one

```
/**
 * maxLength extension function makes a filter that 
 * will constrain edits not to make the length of the text
 * greater than the specified length.
 * 
 * @param max
 */
fun EditText.maxLength(max: Int){
    this.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilter.LengthFilter(max))
}
```

---

```
editText?.maxLength(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution for SWIFT 5

```
editText.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilter.LengthFilter(123))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Title");


                    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
//for Limit...                    
input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(3)});
                    builder.setView(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

best solution i found

```
textView.setText(text.substring(0,10));
```

Comment: It won't limit a length of `EditText`, but cuts off a text after 10th symbol (one time).

Answer (score 0):

To keep the original input filter, you can do it this way:

```
InputFilter.LengthFilter maxLengthFilter = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(100);
        InputFilter[] origin = contentEt.getFilters();
        InputFilter[] newFilters;
        if (origin != null && origin.length > 0) {
            newFilters = new InputFilter[origin.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(origin, 0, newFilters, 0, origin.length);
            newFilters[origin.length] = maxLengthFilter;
        } else {
            newFilters = new InputFilter[]{maxLengthFilter};
        }
        contentEt.setFilters(newFilters);
```