# What's the best way to limit text length of EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, maxlength

What's the best way to limit the text length of an `EditText` in Android?

Is there a way to do this via xml?

Comment: I wanted to set the maximum number of characters for my EditText. At first it was not obvious that text length limit was the same thing. (Just a note for another confuse traveller).

Comment: The **correct answer is here**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19222238/276949. This answer limits the length AND prevents a buffer from continously filling after hitting the limit,  therefore allowing your **backspace key** to work properly.

Answer (score 1603, accepted):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLength)

[Example](http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/numeric-edittext-and-edittext-with-max.html)

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

Comment: D'oh! The same thing happened to me. I was looking at the code, and there isn't a setMaxLength method.

Comment: what does the Check here do? It just links to this page.

Comment: I think someone thought it would be clever to have the click here page linked to here. When I originally wrote the answer it linked to the Android developers page but edits were made since. I'll traverse the history and request a change to link it back.

Comment: @Vincy, you are incorrect.  The `maxLength` property still works.

Comment: Be aware that `android:maxLength` is equivalent to `InputFilter.LengthFilter`, so when programmatically changing it's filter, you have modified its XML filter as well.

Comment: To the people who says it doesn't work, be aware that calling `setFilters` will stop `android:maxLength` working, because it overwrites the filter set by the XML. In other words, if you set any filters programmatically, you must set them all programmatically.

Comment: @hpique 9 years later, +1 D'oh!  xD

Answer (score 388):

use an input filter to limit the max length of a text view.

```
TextView editEntryView = new TextView(...);
InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];
filterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8);
editEntryView.setFilters(filterArray);
```

Comment: This is very useful if someone already made some `InputFilter`. It overrides `android:maxlength` in xml file, so we need to add `LengthFilter` this way.

Comment: I think your answer is the best answer, since it is more dynamic, +1

Comment: this works, my case: abc.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});

Answer (score 227):

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
int maxLength = 3;    
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
```

Comment: This is similar to the way android does it with the xml.

Comment: How can i set minimum length?

Comment: @AkhilaMadari, probably with `TextWatcher`.

Answer (score 79):

I have had this problem and I consider we are missing a well explained way of doing this programmatically without losing the already set filters.

**Setting the length in XML:**

As the accepted answer states correctly, if you want to define a fixed length to an EditText which you won't change further in the future just define in your EditText XML:

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

**Setting the length programmatically**

To set the length programmatically you'll need to set it through an `InputFilter`. But if you create a new InputFilter and set it to the `EditText` you will lose all the other already defined filters (e.g. maxLines, inputType, etc) which you might have added either through XML or programatically.

So this is **WRONG**:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
```

To avoid losing previously added filters you need to get those filters, add the new one (maxLength in this case), and set the filters back to the `EditText` as follow:

**Java**

```
InputFilter[] editFilters = editText.getFilters();
InputFilter[] newFilters = new InputFilter[editFilters.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(editFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, editFilters.length);
newFilters[editFilters.length] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength); 
editText.setFilters(newFilters);
```

**Kotlin** however made it easier for everyone, you also need to add the filter to the already existing ones but you can achieve that with a simple:

```
editText.filters += InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)
```

Comment: +1. Didn't know about the filters. Otoh, after comparing the Java and Kotlin code I wonder why people keep insisting on Java for Android development xd.

Comment: I did something like this in KOTLIN: myEdt.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(MAX_LENGTH))

Answer (score 73):

A note to people who are already using a custom input filter and *also* want to limit the max length:

When you assign input filters in code all previously set input filters are cleared, including one set with `android:maxLength`. I found this out when attempting to use a custom input filter to prevent the use of some characters that we don't allow in a password field. After setting that filter with setFilters the maxLength was no longer observed. The solution was to set maxLength and my custom filter together programmatically. Something like this:

```
myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
        new PasswordCharFilter(), new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20)
});
```

Comment: You could retrieve existing filters first as ,
InputFilter[] existingFilters = editText.getFilters();

Then add your filter along with this existing filters

Answer (score 41):

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilter.LengthFilter(250) });
```

Comment: Sure, only for android

Answer (score 24):

For anyone else wondering how to achieve this, here is my extended `EditText` class `EditTextNumeric`.

`.setMaxLength(int)` - sets maximum number of digits

`.setMaxValue(int)` - limit maximum integer value

`.setMin(int)` - limit minimum integer value

`.getValue()` - get integer value

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditTextNumeric extends EditText {
    protected int max_value = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    protected int min_value = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    // constructor
    public EditTextNumeric(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    }

    // checks whether the limits are set and corrects them if not within limits
    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int after) {
        if (max_value != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            try {
                if (Integer.parseInt(this.getText().toString()) > max_value) {
                    // change value and keep cursor position
                    int selection = this.getSelectionStart();
                    this.setText(String.valueOf(max_value));
                    if (selection >= this.getText().toString().length()) {
                        selection = this.getText().toString().length();
                    }
                    this.setSelection(selection);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);
            }
        }
        if (min_value != Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            try {
                if (Integer.parseInt(this.getText().toString()) < min_value) {
                    // change value and keep cursor position
                    int selection = this.getSelectionStart();
                    this.setText(String.valueOf(min_value));
                    if (selection >= this.getText().toString().length()) {
                        selection = this.getText().toString().length();
                    }
                    this.setSelection(selection);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);
            }
        }
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);
    }

    // set the max number of digits the user can enter
    public void setMaxLength(int length) {
        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length);
        this.setFilters(FilterArray);
    }

    // set the maximum integer value the user can enter.
    // if exeeded, input value will become equal to the set limit
    public void setMaxValue(int value) {
        max_value = value;
    }
    // set the minimum integer value the user can enter.
    // if entered value is inferior, input value will become equal to the set limit
    public void setMinValue(int value) {
        min_value = value;
    }

    // returns integer value or 0 if errorous value
    public int getValue() {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(this.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
final EditTextNumeric input = new EditTextNumeric(this);
input.setMaxLength(5);
input.setMaxValue(total_pages);
input.setMinValue(1);
```

All other methods and attributes that apply to `EditText`, of course work too.

Comment: It would be better if we add this in xml Layout. I am getting error with this when using xml 

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class com.passenger.ucabs.utils.EditTextNumeric

Comment: @Martynas Got the same error like Shihab_returns any solution?

Answer (score 24):

**Xml**

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

**Java:**

```
InputFilter[] editFilters = editText.getFilters();
InputFilter[] newFilters = new InputFilter[editFilters.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(editFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, editFilters.length);
newFilters[editFilters.length] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
editText.setFilters(newFilters);
```

**Kotlin:**

```
editText.filters += InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)
```

Answer (score 18):

Due to goto10's observation, I put together the following code to protected against loosing other filters with setting the max length:

```
/**
 * This sets the maximum length in characters of an EditText view. Since the
 * max length must be done with a filter, this method gets the current
 * filters. If there is already a length filter in the view, it will replace
 * it, otherwise, it will add the max length filter preserving the other
 * 
 * @param view
 * @param length
 */
public static void setMaxLength(EditText view, int length) {
    InputFilter curFilters[];
    InputFilter.LengthFilter lengthFilter;
    int idx;

    lengthFilter = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length);

    curFilters = view.getFilters();
    if (curFilters != null) {
        for (idx = 0; idx < curFilters.length; idx++) {
            if (curFilters[idx] instanceof InputFilter.LengthFilter) {
                curFilters[idx] = lengthFilter;
                return;
            }
        }

        // since the length filter was not part of the list, but
        // there are filters, then add the length filter
        InputFilter newFilters[] = new InputFilter[curFilters.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(curFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, curFilters.length);
        newFilters[curFilters.length] = lengthFilter;
        view.setFilters(newFilters);
    } else {
        view.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { lengthFilter });
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to update the code slightly. The array allocated needs to be curFilters.length + 1 in size and after you create newFilters, you didn't set "this" to the newly allocated array.            InputFilter newFilters[] = new InputFilter[curFilters.length + 1];                  System.arraycopy(curFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, curFilters.length);
          this.setFilters(newFilters);

Answer (score 16):

```
//Set Length filter. Restricting to 10 characters only
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(MAX_LENGTH)});

//Allowing only upper case characters
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});

//Attaching multiple filters
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(MAX_LENGTH), new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

Answer (score 12):

Another way you can achieve this is by adding the following definition to the XML file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="6"
    android:hint="@string/hint_gov"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

This will limit the maximum length of the `EditText` widget to 6 characters.

Answer (score 12):

XML

`android:maxLength="10"`

Programmatically:

```
int maxLength = 10;
InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
yourEditText.setFilters(filters);
```

---

Note: internally, EditText & TextView parse the value of `android:maxLength` in XML and use `InputFilter.LengthFilter()` to apply it.

See: [TextView.java#L1564](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L1564)

Answer (score 11):

From [material.io](http://material.io), you can use `TextInputEditText` combined with `TextInputLayout`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="1000"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="false">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:hint="@string/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="1000"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

You can configure a password EditText with drawable:

[image: password example]

Or you can limit text length with/without a counter:

[image: counter example]

Dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin:

```
edit_text.filters += InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)
```

`ZTE Blade A520` has strange effect. When you type more than 10 symbols (for instance, 15), `EditText` shows first 10, but other 5 are not visible and not accessible. But when you delete symbols with `Backspace`, it first deletes right 5 symbols and then removes remaining 10. To overcome this behaviour use [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19222238/2914140):

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
android:maxLength="10"
```

or this:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

or this, if you want to have suggestions:

```
private class EditTextWatcher(private val view: EditText) : TextWatcher {
    private var position = 0
    private var oldText = ""

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) = Unit

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        oldText = s?.toString() ?: ""
        position = view.selectionStart
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        val newText = s?.toString() ?: ""
        if (newText.length > 10) {
            with(view) {
                setText(oldText)
                position = if (start > 0 && count > 2) {
                    // Text paste in nonempty field.
                    start
                } else {
                    if (position in 1..10 + 1) {
                        // Symbol paste in the beginning or middle of the field.
                        position - 1
                    } else {
                        if (start > 0) {
                            // Adding symbol to the end of the field.
                            start - 1
                        } else {
                            // Text paste in the empty field.
                            0
                        }
                    }
                }
                setSelection(position)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Usage:
editTextWatcher = EditTextWatcher(view.edit_text)
view.edit_text.addTextChangedListener(editTextWatcher)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a custom EditText Class that allow Length filter to live along with other filters.
Thanks to Tim Gallagher's Answer (below)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class EditTextMultiFiltering extends EditText{

    public EditTextMultiFiltering(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EditTextMultiFiltering(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public EditTextMultiFiltering(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setMaxLength(int length) {
        InputFilter curFilters[];
        InputFilter.LengthFilter lengthFilter;
        int idx;

        lengthFilter = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length);

        curFilters = this.getFilters();
        if (curFilters != null) {
            for (idx = 0; idx < curFilters.length; idx++) {
                if (curFilters[idx] instanceof InputFilter.LengthFilter) {
                    curFilters[idx] = lengthFilter;
                    return;
                }
            }

            // since the length filter was not part of the list, but
            // there are filters, then add the length filter
            InputFilter newFilters[] = new InputFilter[curFilters.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(curFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, curFilters.length);
            newFilters[curFilters.length] = lengthFilter;
            this.setFilters(newFilters);
        } else {
            this.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { lengthFilter });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it simple way in xml:

```
android:maxLength="4"
```

if u require to set 4 character in xml edit-text so,use this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtUserCode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:hint="Enter user code" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this for ***Java* programmatically**:

```
myEditText(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(CUSTOM_MAX_LEN)});
```

Comment: You forgot to call the method so it should look like : `myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(CUSTOM_MAX_LEN)});
`

Answer (score 3):

it simple way in xml:

```
android:maxLength="@{length}"
```

for setting it programmatically you can use the following function

```
public static void setMaxLengthOfEditText(EditText editText, int length) {
    InputFilter[] filters = editText.getFilters();
    List arrayList = new ArrayList();
    int i2 = 0;
    if (filters != null && filters.length > 0) {
        int filtersSize = filters.length;
        int i3 = 0;
        while (i2 < filtersSize) {
            Object obj = filters[i2];
            if (obj instanceof LengthFilter) {
                arrayList.add(new LengthFilter(length));
                i3 = 1;
            } else {
                arrayList.add(obj);
            }
            i2++;
        }
        i2 = i3;
    }
    if (i2 == 0) {
        arrayList.add(new LengthFilter(length));
    }
    if (!arrayList.isEmpty()) {
        editText.setFilters((InputFilter[]) arrayList.toArray(new InputFilter[arrayList.size()]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine...

`android:maxLength="10"`

this will accept only `10` characters.

Answer (score 2):

I was using "maxLength" but it didn't work for me. So, based on my experience, I tried a few things.
And I detected the problem.
I must declare the id.
Then:

```
android:id="@+id/editTextTest"
android:maxLength="10"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had saw a lot of good solutions, but I'd like to give a what I think as more complete and user-friendly solution, which include:

1, Limit length.
2, If input more, give a callback to trigger your toast.
3, Cursor can be at middle or tail.
4, User can input by paste a string.
5, Always discard overflow input and keep origin.

```
public class LimitTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    public interface IF_callback{
        void callback(int left);
    }

    public IF_callback if_callback;

    EditText editText;
    int maxLength;

    int cursorPositionLast;
    String textLast;
    boolean bypass;

    public LimitTextWatcher(EditText editText, int maxLength, IF_callback if_callback) {

        this.editText = editText;
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
        this.if_callback = if_callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        if (bypass) {

            bypass = false;

        } else {

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append(s);
            textLast = stringBuilder.toString();

            this.cursorPositionLast = editText.getSelectionStart();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.toString().length() > maxLength) {

            int left = maxLength - s.toString().length();

            bypass = true;
            s.clear();

            bypass = true;
            s.append(textLast);

            editText.setSelection(this.cursorPositionLast);

            if (if_callback != null) {
                if_callback.callback(left);
            }
        }

    }

}


edit_text.addTextChangedListener(new LimitTextWatcher(edit_text, MAX_LENGTH, new LimitTextWatcher.IF_callback() {
    @Override
    public void callback(int left) {
        if(left <= 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "input is full", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}));
```

What I failed to do is, if user highlight a part of the current input and try to paste an very long string, I don't know how to restore the highlight.

Such as, max length is set to 10, user inputed '12345678', and mark '345' as highlight, and try to paste a string of '0000' which will exceed limitation.

When I try to use edit_text.setSelection(start=2, end=4) to restore origin status, the result is, it just insert 2 space as '12 345 678', not the origin highlight. I'd like someone solve that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:maxLength="10"` in the EditText.(Here the limit is upto 10 characters)