# How do you set the max number of characters for an EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How do you set the max number of characters for an Android EditText input?  I see setMaxLines, setMaxEMS, but nothing for the number of characters.

Comment: Also, the SO answer [here][1] to set the max length dynamically


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4145983/530513

Answer (score 274):

In XML you can add this line to the `EditText` `View` where 140 is the maximum number of characters:

```
android:maxLength="140"
```

Comment: can you lead me how can we achieve this by using the properties tab in the eclipse's xml graphical view?

Comment: @NiteshVerma 
in your res/layout xml file put next 

'<LinearLayout....
  <EditText
       android:maxLength="20"'

Comment: why it ignore space ? :/

Answer (score 65):

Dynamically:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(MAX_NUM) });
```

Via xml:

```
<EditText
    android:maxLength="@integer/max_edittext_length"
```

Answer (score 45):

You can use a InputFilter, that's the way:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10); //Filter to 10 characters
myEditText .setFilters(filters);
```

Answer (score 7):

I always set the max like this:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_blaze_it
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/too_high"

    <!-- This is the line you need to write to set the max-->
        android:maxLength="420"
        />
```

Answer (score 4):

It is working for me.

```
    etMsgDescription.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maximum_character)});

    etMsgDescription.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            tvCharacterLimite.setText(" "+String.valueOf(maximum_character - etMsgDescription.getText().length()));
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter device name"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:inputType="textFilter"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
```

InputType has to set "textFilter"

```
        android:inputType="textFilter"
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function anywhere easily:

```
 public static void setEditTextMaxLength(EditText editText, int length) {
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length);
    editText.setFilters(FilterArray);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin way

```
editText.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength))
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me this way, it's the best I've found. 
It is for a max length of 200 characters

```
editObservations.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (editObservations.getText().length() >= 201){
                String str = editObservations.getText().toString().substring(0, 200);
                editObservations.setText(str);
                editObservations.setSelection(str.length());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can use maxLength in xml or InputFilter.LengthFilter as answered above. But for me in some cases, it was not enough. I created a class for more flexible settings of EditText: https://github.com/devapro/NumberWatcher
It is implementation only for numbers input, but you can change it for any of the types.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work from XML with maxLenght
I used this code, you can limit the number of characters

> `String editorName = mEditorNameNd.getText().toString().substring(0, Math.min(mEditorNameNd.length(), 15));`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a validation hook to a submit or change event.

```
if (EditText.length() <=10){
            Toast.makeText(MainAcitvity.this, "Enter Valid Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            contact.setError("Enter Valid");
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).