# Android-Prevent the user from entering more than 4 numbers in editbox

Tags: android, android-edittext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android How do you set the max number of characters for an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066212/android-how-do-you-set-the-max-number-of-characters-for-an-edittext)

How can I prevent the user from entering more than 4 numbers in edittext ?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly easy task that can be learned from documentation, but nevertheless.

The answer to your question consists of two parts:

1. How to allow user to input digits only
2. How to restrict field length to maximum of 4 chars.

The first part can be achieved using `android:inputType="number"`. The other one can be achieved by using `android:maxLength` field. So the final result would be:

```
<EditText  ...
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:lines="1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks , is it possible to have inputtype for characters (A to Z ) only ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `maxLength` property of the EditText equal to 4.