# Limit text length in edit text

Tags: android

I want to limit the text length of edit text ui element via code:

```
EditText et = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.smsBody);;
int maxLength = 300;

InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
et.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

But this gives me a null pointer exception in the last line. Any ideas whats wrong? This codes is in the `onPostExecute` method of my async task class. `Parent` is the main activity.

Comment: Check whether the et variable is not null. If it is null then it was not found in the parent layout.

Comment: but that makes no sence because its actually there^^

Comment: I would bet that @Flo is right, et is probably coming back null from findViewById(). Post some more of your code(Specifically  anything related to the parent reference) and if possible explain the context of your layouts (i.e. are we inside the main layout of an activity? In a dialog within an activity? etc) Try using YourActivity.findViewById(), instead of parent.findViewById()

Comment: oh I just realized that parent is wrong, its not the main layout but another layout, how can I access it?

Comment: ComposeActivity.findViewById(R.id.smsBody); seems to be wrong

Comment: findViewById() is not a static method so you can't call it like that. You need an instance of it or call it within the Activity itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit text length of EditText in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285412/limit-text-length-of-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to put in your .xml file under your edit text:

android:maxLength="300"

You dont need any of that other stuff in your .java file. Your .xml file controls things like color, length, size, etc.

Comment: Also you dont need "parent" when finding your editText. that might be what is causing your null pointer. instead of: EditText et = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.smsBody); Use: EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smsBody); This is how i have done it in all my android project.