# Limit a number edittext entry to 10 million

Tags: android, android-edittext, limit, data-entry

I have a "**number edittext**". I want to limit the entry of the "**number edittext**" to 10 million. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set limit in Edit Text for this purpose. try following code

```
android:maxLength="9"
```

This  will allow you to add number upto 999999999 Rs.

Answer (score 2):

[Limit text length of EditText in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285412/limit-text-length-of-edittext-in-android)
I am not sure what you mean exactly but i am guessing you don't want the text box size to be more than 1 and 7 zeros, i think the above link should help you if that's the case.