# Specify the number of characters in edit text in android

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I have a small trick on how to restrict the number of characters in an `edit text` in android..for example I want to put a limit say 10 characters for the name field, so it will not allow the user to enter more than 10 characters.

Also, I have another problem in specifying the `inputtype` for text, I know the procedure which is `android:inputType="text|textPersonName"` but it dosen't work since it allows the user to enter characters, numbers and also special characters.

I will much appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

Use following xml attributes to set maximum characters and digits to allow

```
android:digits
android:maxLength
```

For ex:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/et_name"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ."
android:maxLength="10" />
```

Here, This allows only lower case alphabets, space and dot (.)

**Upate**

set filter by java

```
InputFilter myFilter = new InputFilter() { 
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 


                        if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))) { 
                                return ""; 
                        } 

                        if (i == start) {
                           return source.toUpperCase();
                        }

                } 
                return source; 
        } 
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{myFilter});
```

Comment: Oh it works well with digits attribute, but is there a way to make the first letter uppercase and the rest lower?

Comment: its not possible to do in xml, you've set filter, see updated answer.

Comment: I did wat you've said but I got an error in return source.toUpperCase; the error under toUpperCase

Comment: check updated ans. use source.toUpperCase(); instead of source.toUpperCase;, if again returns any error post error log

Comment: @ZiZo use `source.toString().toUpperCase();` as source is a `CharSequence` type and `toUpperCase()` is accessable for `String` type values.

Answer (score 3):

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

in EditText in XML file.

Comment: thx so much this is worked perfectly. But how about the input type text, do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part what you have to do is write:

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

as far as your second question is concerned writing only textPersonName is sufficient

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
```

as referenced here [input type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

You have to use bit flags only when doing it programaticaly,which would correspond to:

```
 setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT  | InputType. TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
```

Comment: i think it is enough to modify your xml to android:inputType="textPersonName" it is really not necesary to do it by code

Comment: if you really want to do it by code,you have to do it after you get your edittext from the xml:
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText); editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType. TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);

Comment: when I do it using this attribute android:inputType="textPersonName" when the emulato runs it allows the user to enter alphabets, numbers and special characters. But when I d it using th line of code that you provided I got an error in the second line which is editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType. TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME); a red line under setInputType, "|" and "."

Answer (score 1):

For setting the restriction on the number of characters you should use as already posted

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

in the EditText in XML File. And if you want the user to restrict to only alphabets then you will have to create a custom input filter in JAVA code as follows

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                        if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))) { 
                                return ""; 
                        } 
                } 
                return null; 
        } 
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android).

Comment: oh this is perfect but for the filter code where I have to put it in order to be applied only on the edit text of the person name?

Comment: In my last line edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter}); I am setting the filter to the EditText named edit. Similarly you put the filter on your EditText.

Comment: the error is syntax error on token "setFilters", = expected after this token

Comment: you need to write "edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});" where "edit" is the name of your EditText. 
edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});

Comment: ok it works well but it doesn't work with maxLength since it allows the user to enter as many as characters he wants. Any help?

Comment: If android:maxLength="10" does not work then again you could apply a custom filter. Look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285412/limit-text-length-of-edittext-in-android

Comment: this is the xml  <EditText 
         android:id="@+id/edittext1"  
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:inputType="textPersonName"   
       
     />

Comment: and this is the main.java

InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() 
 {  
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,  
Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) 
        {  
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) 
                {  
                        if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))) 
                        {  
                                return "";  
                  }     
                }return null;  
        }}; 
edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1); 
edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5)});

Comment: but I need the first letter to be uppercase. Could you help me?

Comment: Use this in your xml android:inputType="textCapSentences" or android:capitalize="sentences".

Answer (score 1):

**Only  7, 8 ,9  digits start in Mobile number first character in android Working**

Source Code

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzBKpZ4nzNzUQkU3S25fcXV4cEE

First Letter Start with 7,8,9 in Edit  text in android

```
package com.keshav.mobilenumberrestriction_1_6_digits;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et_mobile_feedback;
    String blockCharacterSet = "1234560";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et_mobile_feedback = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mobile_feedback);

        et_mobile_feedback.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });

        et_mobile_feedback.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // you can call or do what you want with your EditText here
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(et_mobile_feedback.getText().toString().length()==0)
                    blockCharacterSet="1234560";
                else
                    blockCharacterSet="";
                if(et_mobile_feedback.getText().toString().length()==10)
                    blockCharacterSet="1234567890";
            }
        });
    }
    private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            try {
                if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains("" + source.charAt(0))) {
                    return "";
                }
            }catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_mobile_feedback"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:editable="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Mobile"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

it simple way in xml:

if u require to set 4 character in edit-text so,use this

```
android:maxLength="4"
```