# Edit text Max length and show the length in the texview

Tags: android

I have a edit text and a text view and I want to set a Max length in my edit text and it show in my text view and every time a user input a characters it will minus the number of character. For example  I set the Max length of my edit text to 150 and if the user input 150 characters he/she cannot input any-more.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**To set the max length of the EditText (*pick one or the other*):**

1. In your XML file (recommended), use the property `android:maxLength="150"` Ex:

   ```
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/yourEditTextId"
       ...
       android:maxLength="150" />
   ```
2. Programmatically (in your `onCreate` method), like so:

   ```
   EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
   et.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { 
       new InputFilter.LengthFilter(150) // 150 is max length
   });
   ```

---

**To keep a counter of the length left in the EditText:**

Add this listener in your `onCreate` method (or anywhere, but it makes sense in `onCreate`):

```
final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(150 - et.length()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int b, int c) 
    { }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int c, int a) 
    { }
});
```

Comment: every time I input it unfortunately stopped  what's the problem??

Comment: Two things: 1. Post your LogCat errors and 2. Post your entire code. Go to http://pastie.org to do that and send me a link. This code works for me.

Comment: @JeremiahMe There must be more than that in the error message. Either way, you're getting a `NullPointerException`, which means something has not been set a value. Send me the entire class.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the length by using

`editText.setFilters( new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(YOUR_LENGTH) } );`

or in xml

`maxLength = "LENGTH"`

Then you can get set a `TextWatcher` and you can get the String there so length also.

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:maxLength:"150"` for `EditText` in the layout file.

And in the class file implement `addTextChangedListener()` method for the `EditText`

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(150 - s.toString().length()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int b, int c) 
    { }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int c, int a) 
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had saw a lot of good solutions, but I'd like to give a what I think as more complete and user-friendly solution, which include:

1, Limit length.
2, If input more, give a callback to trigger your toast.
3, Cursor can be at middle or tail.
4, User can input by paste a string.
5, Always discard overflow input and keep origin.

here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46922794/2468360

you can use callback to show the left number that can input.

Answer (score -1):

use this       **android:maxLength="150"**

```
        <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText10"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:ems="10"
         android:maxLength="150"
          />
```

Answer (score -1):

In xml use this:

```
android:maxLength="Length_size" // size that you want
```