# How to restrict to give input to auto complete text view after particular length in android?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an auto complete text view and its max length is defined in xml file as below.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/autocompleteTextView"
fontPath="font/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="12"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLength="12"
android:maxLines="1" />
```

but when I select values from suggestions based on my input it still allow me to enter more than 12 numbers.
I am using text watcher for auto complete suggestions.
How to resolve this problem?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718733/edit-text-max-length-and-show-the-length-in-the-texview

Answer (score 1):

**Please try below example code and change textview names as per you required.**

**In Java file or Activity -**

```
@BindView(R.id.tvName)
    AutoCompleteTextView tvName;

        int maxLength = 12;
        InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
        fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
        tvName.setFilters(fArray);
```

**In .xml file :-**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Please enter"/>
```