# Limit the input in an edit text

Tags: android, android-input-filter

I want to write a input filter 
such that if i say the edit text should not have a number higher than 40
you can input 1-40 , but anything else will not work

I do not want to do that with a text watcher, but an InputFilter

how can I do that ?

Comment: You want something like that? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14212734/4224337

Comment: Did you check [that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285412/limit-text-length-of-edittext-in-android)

Comment: @Rami yes this is exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

There's a property of EditText (in xml) called:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

You might be having a button click or something during which you would validate the EditText, there you can do something like this:

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
if(num<1 || num>40)
{
  // display a message that you have to write something to EditText first
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want to limit the length of the text, he wants to limit the numerical values that you can type.

Comment: @Karakuri Oops, my bad! :)