# Limit the number of text in edittext to 13 digits android

Tags: java, android

How can I ensure that the text entered on this edittext is nothing but 13digits. This is my attempt but the user can enter 5 digits but I want it 13 digits

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"/>
```

**updated codes**

```
final EditText phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);

            InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];
            filterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(11);
            phone.setFilters(filterArray);

if(Double.parseDouble(phone.getText().toString()) > 11)
            {
                //the above if text always fails
            }
```

Comment: I think this was addressed before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10723687/5885018

Comment: It has not been addressed. It talks about adding a maxlength but not a constraint to ensure that the maxLength is entered

Comment: It's talking about custom input filters and maxlength (your case).

Comment: please check to see updated codes

Comment: what you need is not limit. Limit is 13 by using `maxLength`. You need min length. You have to check this by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but maybe you could try one of the following:

1. don't setText unless edittext.getText().length()==13 (as I asume you will set it at a certain moment). If it's not the length you want, you can show a message, let's say
2. add a TextWatcher (through onTextChangedListener) on edittext and keep track of user input