# Set InputFilter for white space and maximum length

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, input-filter

I want to use Input filter where I can prevent first space entering AND max length of my edit text limited to 200 characters.

so far I have this:
Hot to I put the maxlength into the same filter

```js
 private void setInputFilterForEmailAndPwd(final EditText amountEditText) {
 InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
     public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
      if (Character.isSpace(source.charAt(i))) {
   return "";
      }
  }
  
  return null;
     }
 };

 amountEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
    }



setInputFilterForEmailAndPwd(emailEdit);
```

Comment: try this<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285412/limit-text-length-of-edittext-in-android>.

Comment: I tried that, It doesnt work for me

Comment: try the following snippet :-

InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(200), myFirstSpaceFilter}; // myFirstSpaceFilter is the filter that you have already creatd 
amountEditText.setFilters(filters);

Comment: it wont work like that either, what to I need to change in my method setInputFilterForEmailAndPwd  in order to work like this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution
I put new Input Filter, instead of setInputFilterForEmailAndPwd:

```js
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
     public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
      if (Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(i))) {
   return "";
      }
  }
  return null;
     }
 };
```

and then:

```js
 emailEdit.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(200) });
```