# Android custom Keyboard issues with edittext max length

Tags: android, android-edittext, custom-keyboard, android-keypad, android-input-method

I have been facing an issue for quite some time now and could not find a solution for it, hence approaching StackOverflow.

I have developed a Custom keyboard.
All the functionalities are working well except for one small glitch.

I have developed a test app to test the custom keyboard in which for an EditText, have given the maxlength property (Assume maxlength as 10). When we are trying to type in that EditText the text shown in the EditText only for 10 chars as expected. If we continue typing even after the 10 chars it is not displayed in the UI but suggestions are shown and also when we use backspace it won't clear the visible character in the EditText, instead first it clears the extra chars that are input and then once the length is 10 it will start to remove the visible characters.

As the code is too big to post here I am updating the screen shots of the issue so that it would be easy to understand.

[image]
[image]

I have searched regarding this but always getting answers to add max length to edit text, which is not in my control.

I am thinking if we can get the maxlength property of the current focused edittext in the keyboard, we can overcome this issue.

1) Is my above assumption a valid one

2) If yes, is there a way to get the current focused edittext property in my input service?

Any inputs will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: pls. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285412/limit-text-length-of-edittext-in-android

Comment: That won't help. As I have already mentioned in my question the edittext part of some other app using keyboard is not in my hand, only the keyboard part is in my hand.

Comment: You can figure out using its `length` or `type-in` words and use condition

Comment: The question was all about that.... How to figure out that length from my input service?

Comment: I'm sorry I have no further knowledge about it However only `detect type-in words`

Comment: 5yrs and I found myself in the exact same problem. Have you found any solution?