# Set Limit To EditText

Tags: java, android

I want to set a minimum value of in the EditText so the user can't enter a number less than 50.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_width="150.0dip"
                android:hint="(min 50)"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number" />
```

Comment: When do you want the testing to be done? While writing, when button is clicked...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit text length of EditText in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285412/limit-text-length-of-edittext-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to define a min and max value for EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android)

Comment: Both . :D Can u help me?

Comment: @Sergio i want when button is clicked.

Comment: There are a lot of Questions like that, just search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing when the button is clicked.

You put this into the listener of the button:

```
if (Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString()) < 50) {
    // Do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use TextWatcher. Here are simple steps to follow:

STEP 1 - Bring the EditText (or View) that you want to track into Java code

STEP 2 - Implement TextWatcher in your Activity or create a separate class at handles he responsibility of managing text changes (Implementation is  similar to other listeners s.a. OnClickListener)

STEP 3 - Implement all the methods inside the TextWatcher (@Override interface methods)

STEP 4 - Use the addTextChangedListener method on the View (EditText) to link it to the TextWatcher (register the view)

STEP 5 - Use one of the available methods to perform the validation

Upon implementation, there will be 3 methods we must override from the interface:

```
void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int i, int i2, int i3) {}
void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int i, int i2, int i3) {} 
void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {}
```

All these three methods are called consequently upon any change (like typing or deleting a letter). It's enough to use just one of them, and it's preferable to use the afterTextChanged method. EDITABLE parameter is just a text which we have inside our EditText at the time instant.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **InputFilter** class

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

private int min, max;

public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
    this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
    this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    try {
        int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
        if (isInRange(min, max, input))
            return null;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    return "";
}

private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
    return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
}
```

}

You should get a reference of you Edit Text class on your Activity/Fragment

```
EditText yourEditext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

InputFilter[] editFilters = yourEditext.getFilters();
                InputFilter[] newFilters = new InputFilter[editFilters.length + 1];
                System.arraycopy(editFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, editFilters.length);
                newFilters[editFilters.length] = new InputFilterMinMax(0, 59);
                yourEditext.setFilters(newFilters);
```