# how to set limit to edit text limit in kotlinlang

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

*hi i want set limit for my text edit in* **kotlin**
**please help...!**
[i want set 3 digit number for each of this inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2J8O.jpg)

```
        var num1=edt_no.text
        var num2=edt_ntw.text
        var num3=edt_nth.text
        var num4=edt_f.text
        when{
            edt_no.text.isEmpty() -> txt_res.text="First is empty"
            edt_ntw.text.isEmpty() -> txt_res.text="second is empty"
            edt_nth.text.isEmpty() -> txt_res.text="third is empty"
            edt_f.text.isEmpty() -> txt_res.text="Fourth is empty"
            else -> calc(num1,num2,num3,num4)
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit text length of EditText in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285412/limit-text-length-of-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 attributes for each `EditText`:

```
android:maxLength="3"
android:inputType="number"
```