# EditText : set number of characters programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a `EditText` , and I would like to restrict the **number of characters** which could be inputted in this `EditText`, and make this restriction **programmatically**, how to do it? For example, say I would like to restrict it to only allow 10 characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically set maxLength in Android TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461824/how-to-programmatically-set-maxlength-in-android-textview)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can Use [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) for restricting the number of characters in EditView programmatically as:

```
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);
your_edittext.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

for more help you can see this tutorial for restricting  number of characters in EditView:

https://web.archive.org/web/20200222150701/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/02/maxlength-in-edittext-using-codes.html

Answer (score 1):

I would implement a filter:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

   @Override
   public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
      if (source.length > 10){
       //cancel the edit or whatever
      }
   }
};
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rg);
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {filter});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setEditTextMaxLength(int length) {
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length);
    edt_text.setFilters(FilterArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this my friend easy game easy life

`InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5);
input.setFilters(FilterArray);`