# How to set multiple InputFilters on EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
int maxLength = 20;
private String blockCharacterSet = "~#^|$%'&*!;";

private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter()
{

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {

        if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

Here only one filter is working either blockCharacterSet or max length:

```
EditText etname;
etname.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
etname.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
```

Can anyone please help me to set above two filters at a time?

Comment: Check the soln here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414540/edittext-set-number-of-characters-programmatically

Comment: already i try this but no use

Comment: Try Akshay's soln

Comment: @veeraprasad got any solution?

Answer (score 14):

If you have two inputFilters, add it in array like below:

```
etname.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength), filter});
```

Finally the `setFilter()` takes array of input filters, so in the array you create in `setFilters()` should contain all the input filters.

Comment: ThanQ so much Your suggestion works.... we were using && to connet these filters...