# How to set Edittext to multiline?

Tags: android-edittext, android-xml, multiline

I tried setting my EditText to multiline once and it worked.  But when I changed some stuff on the EditText to make it look a bit cool, it doesn't type in multiline anymore.

```
<EditText
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="  "
        android:id="@+id/reqdesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:hint="   Enter your request here"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:maxLength="80"
        android:background="@layout/rounded_border_edittext"
        android:lines="8"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/post"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: Probably this: `android:layout_height="110dp"`. Make it `wrap_content`

Comment: Try removing `ems`.

Comment: @R.Zagórski: It's still not working

Comment: @Wizard: It's also not working

Comment: remove `android:lines="8"`

Comment: @user5599807: not working as well

Comment: try removing the maxLength attribute. I think it's making the edit text not to go to the next line.

Comment: @Bharat: It's also not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
reqdesc = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.reqdesc);
reqdesc.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
             InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE |
            InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
    fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
    reqdesc.setFilters(fArray);
```

It now works, I put these lines of codes under onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Find your `Edittext`

```
etReqdesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reqdesc);
```

Now programetically call: inside `onCreate()`

```
etReqdesc.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
etReqdesc.setSingleLine(false);
etReqdesc.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);
```

your edittext should look like:

```
<EditText
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="  "
    android:id="@+id/reqdesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:hint="   Enter your request here"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="@layout/rounded_border_edittext"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/post"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Remove `android:maxLength="80"` attribute.

Comment: how to programatically set the maximum length?

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461824/how-to-programmatically-set-maxlength-in-android-textview)

Comment: I cleaned the project but it still doesn't go to the next line